# Restructure matrix to get back original matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

In the code below, I generate a random 8 x 5 matrix then create a new matrix 'temp' that is A restructured to `temp = reshape(A',r*c,1);`.  I then do some manipulation on temp (but keep the dimension 40 x 1).  How do you restructure 'temp' now to get back a matrix with the dimension as A (i.e. revert temp back now to a 8 x 5 matrix)?

Thanks.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
A = randi(10,8,5);
[r c] = size(A);
temp = reshape(A',r*c,1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you construct `temp` from a `reshape` operation on the transpose of matrix `A` (`A'`), you can simply re-transform back to the original `A` form by an additional `reshape` operation applied to `temp`, but with row and column count, `r` and `c`, respectively, applied "as reverse" (as column and row count, respectively), followed by finally transposing the resulting reshaped matrix.

```
%// ... perform some manipulations (not affecting size) of temp

%// restructure back to the form of A
backToAForm = reshape(temp,c,r)'
```